# Image no loading for some pages in default layout cakephp?

Tags: php, image, cakephp, layout

I added a image as a button in my default layout of my cakephp site.
but that images is not loading for some views.

```
<input type="image" class="search_button" src="img/search.png" style="background-color: #066; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: -5px; vertical-align:  middle" />
```

image is in the webroot, img folder

Comment: 1. open the console on the google chrome.
2. Go to console
3. If image path is wrong, the console will give error like -> failed to load resource and then the path of image will be given
4. see whats gone wrong with that faulty path and correct it :)

Comment: how to open console on the google chrome

Comment: F12 key and then see right most tab 'Console'

Comment: yes problem with the path ! i use <img> now working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use helpers or absolute urls

The problem you have is that the url used to access the image is relative to the current url

Meaning if the current page is:

```
http://example.com
```

The image is requested from

```
http://example.com/img/search.png
```

Let's assume the above image exists. If the current page is:

```
http://example.com/some/text
```

The image is requested from

```
http://example.com/some/text/img/search.png
```

Which does *not* exist.

Appropriate action is to either use an absolute url

```
<input type="image" class="search_button" src="/img/search.png"
                                               ^
```

Or use an appropriate helper method to generate the markup. In this case however - it would be better to use css:

```
// file in webroot/css/foo.css
.search_button {
    background-image:url('../img/search.png');
}
```