# Cakephp Image not showing in view.ctp

Tags: javascript, php, cakephp

I want to insert a rating star to my page using CakePHP. The path to the image is in javascript as below. But, the image didn't show.

```
$.fn.jRating = function(op) {
        var defaults = {
            /** String vars **/
            bigStarsPath : '../img/icons/stars.png' , // path of the icon stars.png
            smallStarsPath : '../img/icons/small.png', // path of the icon small.png
            phpPath : 'app/jRating.php', // path of the php file jRating.php
            type : 'big', // can be set to 'small' or 'big'
```

I already try using `<?php echo $this->webroot; ?>img/icons/stars.png`. but no luck. can anyone help me.

Comment: Use an absolute url -  why are you referencing "app" at all?

Comment: sorry i didnt understand what u mean. can u please explain 'absolute url'

Comment: `bigStarsPath : '..` <- delete the dots point at an unambiguous location that doesn't depend on the current url. [Here's a similar question with the same problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853175/image-no-loading-for-some-pages-in-default-layout-cakephp/20859809#20859809)

Comment: i already try bigStarsPath : 'img/icons/stars.png', but still the image not showing.

Comment: well that's not surprising since that's _also_ a relative path. Look at the image you're requesting (use your browser's development tools or server access logs) and compare that to where the image actually is.

Comment: This javascript code is written in .ctp file or .js file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I always do in my layout is to put a javascript variable like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var root = '<?php echo $this->Html->url('/'); ?>';
</script>
```

This way you always have reference to the root of your project.

Then your code will be:

```
$.fn.jRating = function(op) {
    var defaults = {
        /** String vars **/
        bigStarsPath : root+'img/icons/stars.png' , // path of the icon stars.png
        smallStarsPath : root+'img/icons/small.png', // path of the icon small.png
        phpPath : 'app/jRating.php', // path of the php file jRating.php
        type : 'big', // can be set to 'small' or 'big'
```

The problem which I see here is that phpPath point to app/ which I believe is invisible since the root of the project is set to app/webroot/.

So either move your file jRating.php to app/webroot/ or move the logic into controller's action.

Comment: sound advice, +1. `phpPath` needs that treatment too probably i.e. + `phpPath : root + 'jRating.php'`.

Comment: thankyou nik chankov! it's really work. something new for me to learn ;p

Answer (score 0):

Use `$this->Html->image()` instead. The function retrieves and adds routing to the image located in `app/webroot/img`.

Docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::image

Answer (score 0):

Use the html helper and just make the URL to be something like this:

```
../folder-name-in-webroot/file-name
```